# Iframe file upload doesent work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I want to upload file with ajax.
So I have a small jquery plugin that adds a button to the page. Once the button is clicked it opens a bootstrap dialog with a form and file input. The Form is submited to ASP MVC method that saves the file and returns json, that is shown in alert.

It works fine in chrome, but in IE the onload function of the iframe is not called and the browser gives me the json for download.
[image]

Server side:

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
     return Json(new { FileName = file.First().FileName });
}
```

Client side:

```
$.fn.fileUpload = function (options) {
    //options
    var settings = $.extend({
        inputName: 'file'
    }, options);

    //variables
    var that = this;
    var index = 0;
    var addFileBtn = $("<button>+</button>");

    var modal = $('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">'+
                      '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">'+
                        '<div class="modal-content">'+
                          '<div class="modal-header">'+
                            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                            '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '<div class="modal-body">' +
                            '<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff"></iframe>' +
                            '<form id="my_form" name="my_form" action="/Home/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="postiframe">' +
                                '<input name="complaintId" value="123"  type="hidden" />'+
                                '<input name="file" id="file" type="file"/>'+
                                '<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn"/>'+
                            '</form>'+
                          '</div>'+
                          '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>'+
                          '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>');

    //init
    addFileBtn.click(function () {
        modal.modal();
        modal.find("#submitBtn").click(function (ev) {
            var form = modal.find('#my_form');

            form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

            modal.find("#postiframe").load(function () {
                var iframeContents = $(this).contents().find("pre").html()
                alert(iframeContents);
            });

            form.submit();
            return false;

        });
    });
    that.append(addFileBtn);
}
```

Comment: Well you are submitting a form and returning JSON. Some browsers will display JSON as plain text, others ask to download it. Sounds like you do not want to return JSON.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the ASP method to return Content(string content) instead of Json and it looks OK. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As epascarello suggested I changed the Asp Mvc method to return Content instead of Json

```
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
     return Content("some string in json format");
}
```

Now the content is loaded in the iframe instead of download prompt.